# About : $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}+\ln\left(x\right)^{2}}dx>\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+\ln\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)dx+1$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, improper-integrals

Prove that :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+\ln\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)dx>\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+\ln\left(x\right)^{2}}\right)dx\right)+1$$

This inequality is quite nice for the eyes but I don't think we can find an exact result for the two integrals  (I don't ask for that).

My attempt :

I have tried to use the inequality  for  $x\geq1$ :

$$\ln{x}\leq(x-1)\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{x^2+x}}.$$

A proof of it can be found here [Which is greater $\frac{13}{32}$ or $\ln \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713384/which-is-greater-frac1332-or-ln-left-frac32-right?noredirect=1&lq=1) and is due to user Michael Rozenberg .

Unfortunately the difficulty is the same and I'm stuck here .Perhaps we can use  the substitution $y=\ln(x)$ .

Question : How to show the first inequality ?

Comment: Maybe these [related questions](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%2B%5Cln%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%7D%24&p=1) will help.

Comment: So you are asking if $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{2}+\ln\left(x\right)^{2}}\,dx > 1$ ?

Comment: @MartinR I think a solution only using a calculator is preferred. A calculator can calculate values of elementary functions such as $\sin \sqrt{2}$ (no special functions such as the Lambert W function).

Comment: The question is also equivalent to $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{1 + x^2 }}\frac{{dx}}{{1 + W_0 (x)}}}  > 1
$$ where $W_0$ is the principal branch of the Lamber $W$-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2 + \ln^2 x}\, \mathrm{d} x > 1.$$

*Fact 1*: For all $y \in (0, \mathrm{e}]$,
$$\frac{-y^4 + 64y^3 - 318y^2 + 400y + 35}{132y + 48} \ge y(1 - \ln y)^2.$$
(*Note*: LHS is the (4, 1)-Pade approximant of $y(1 - \ln y)^2$ at $y = 1$.)

With the substitution $y = \mathrm{e}x$, using Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 & \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2 + \ln^2 x}\, \mathrm{d} x\\
    =\, & \int_0^\mathrm{e} \frac{\mathrm{e}}{y^2 + \mathrm{e}^2 (1 - \ln y)^2}\, \mathrm{d} y\\
 \ge\, & \int_0^\mathrm{e} \frac{132\mathrm{e}y^2 + 48\mathrm{e}y}{(132 - \mathrm{e}^2)y^4 + (64\mathrm{e}^2 + 48)y^3 - 318\mathrm{e}^2 y^2 + 400\mathrm{e}^2y + 35\mathrm{e}^2}\, \mathrm{d} y\\
 \ge\, & \int_0^\mathrm{e} \frac{132\mathrm{e}y^2 + 48\mathrm{e}y}{(132 - \mathrm{e}^2)(y + 1/12)(y + 463/64)[(y - 69/44)^2 + (55/54)^2]}\, \mathrm{d} y  \tag{1}  \\[8pt]  
 =\, & 
 \frac{1253273472\mathrm{e}}{911936989\mathrm{e}^2 - 120375682548} \int_0^\mathrm{e} \frac{1}{12y + 1}\, \mathrm{d} y\\[8pt] 
 &\quad + \frac{29129459463143424\mathrm{e}}{38952637956653\mathrm{e}^2 - 5141748210278196}
 \int_0^\mathrm{e} \frac{1}{64y + 463}\, \mathrm{d} y \\[8pt]
 &\quad + \frac{372594816\mathrm{e}}{2487336612548656836 - 18843459185974673\mathrm{e}^2}\\[8pt]
 &\quad\quad \times \int_0^\mathrm{e} \frac{842186377401732y + 746090344086823}{1411344y^2 - 4426488y + 4934869}\, \mathrm{d} y \tag{2}\\ 
 >\, & 1
\end{align*}
where in (1) we have used (easy): for all $y\in [0, \mathrm{e}]$,
\begin{align*}
 &(132 - \mathrm{e}^2)y^4 + (64\mathrm{e}^2 + 48)y^3 - 318\mathrm{e}^2 y^2 + 400\mathrm{e}^2y + 35\mathrm{e}^2\\
 \le\, & (132 - \mathrm{e}^2)(y + 1/12)(y + 463/64)[(y - 69/44)^2 + (55/54)^2].
\end{align*}
*Note*: The three integrals in (2) admit closed form expressions in terms of $\ln $ and $\arctan$ only.

We are done.